# Запуск app-debug.apk

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk

Компилирую проект через Android Studio, запуск приложения происходит успешно и работает стабильно но, как только кидаю app-debug.apk на телефон и устанавливаю его он просто крашится в момент запуска(устанавливается успешно)
В чем может быть проблема?

P.S. Думал что проблема в файле build.gradle(мол версия андроида не подходит) но там вроде все хорошо

```
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.user_android.otvchat"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}
```

Comment: Может прав каких-то не хватает? Самому приложению имеется ввиду

Comment: Что пишет в лог?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Действительно, проблема была с правами, добавил в AndroidManifest.xml

Знаю что много лишнего скорее всего записал туда но...точно будет запускаться

P.S. Именно столько прав доступа требует Skype

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.microphone"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.wifi"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.location"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.location.network"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.location.gps"
    android:required="false" />

<permission
    android:name="com.skype.android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"
    android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.PERSONAL_INFO"
    android:protectionLevel="normal" />
<permission
    android:name="com.skype.android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_STATS" />

<permission
    android:name="com.skype.raider.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.skype.raider.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<permission
    android:name="com.skype.raider.permission.RECEIVE_ADM_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.skype.raider.permission.RECEIVE_ADM_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.amazon.device.messaging.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.nokia.pushnotifications.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />

<permission
    android:name="com.skype.permission.ACCOUNT"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.skype.permission.ACCOUNT" />
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x20000"
    android:required="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.READ" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.WRITE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.htc.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.htc.launcher.permission.UPDATE_SHORTCUT" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.sonyericsson.home.permission.BROADCAST_BADGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.anddoes.launcher.permission.UPDATE_COUNT" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.majeur.launcher.permission.UPDATE_BADGE" />
```